How to kick a user on discord using discord.py?
I made a discord bot which can automod but I haven't finished it. I tried making the kick function:
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(member='The member you want to kick')
async def joined(ctx, interaction: discord.interactions.Interaction, reason: str , member: Optional[discord.member.Member] = None):
    """Kicks the member."""
    
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Kicked {member} by {ctx.author} for {reason} at <t:{generate_unix_time_code()}:F>')

Error:
File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 887, in decorator
    command = Command(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 666, in __init__
    self._params: Dict[str, CommandParameter] = _extract_parameters_from_callback(callback, callback.__globals__)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 374, in _extract_parameters_from_callback
    param = annotation_to_parameter(resolved, parameter)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\app_commands\transformers.py", line 834, in annotation_to_parameter
    (inner, default, validate_default) = get_supported_annotation(annotation)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\app_commands\transformers.py", line 793, in get_supported_annotation
    raise TypeError(f'unsupported type annotation {annotation!r}')
TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.interactions.Interaction'>

I tried searching around stack overflow but the answers were outdated.

Does this answer your question? How to kick a user using slash commands Discord.py

Please format your code properly as well.
